# Why does `rake db:drop` have a 0 exit status, and raise no error, when it fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I was surprised to discover that, when `rake db:drop` (and assumedly Rails' other built-in raketasks) fails, the bash status code is 0.

```
$ rake db:drop
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
...
$ echo $?
0
```

Perhaps more surprising, it doesn't even raise an error when the task is invoked from within Rails.

```
2.3.0 :001 > begin
2.3.0 :002 >   Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke
2.3.0 :003 >   puts "After raketask invoked"
2.3.0 :004 > end
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
...
After raketask invoked
```

Is this intentional? Digging into the [source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb#L68), this seems to simply call `execute "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS #{quote_table_name(name)}"`. This should [raise an error](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/a953f7f674997517c5b9580335dda3338840aa84/activerecord/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb#L152) on failure. What am I missing?

Comment: What you are missing is a pull request and a reference to the Ruby devs how to handle errors in Unix like operating systems and how to set the exit value of an CLI application like rake :)

Comment: I think this is a problem at the Rails level, not the Ruby level: when a generic raketask fails, it gives a nonzero exit code.

Comment: @Istvan: Perhaps I'm missing your point. Did you mean to imply that this is a genuine bug, and that I should submit a fix to Rails? I had assumed there was a good reason for this, that I was overlooking!

Comment: I was kind of kidding, you can try to fix it though. What I was trying to say that they do not care about this issue a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue fixed in Rails 5: [PR #19924 Explicitly exit with status "1" for create and drop failures](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19924)

Best solution would be to use Rails 5. :) Otherwise, you're stuck with one of:

- Check that the db was dropped another way (could miss other errors).
- Capture stderr output and inspect
- Monkeypatch ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks::drop